# ¿Como hacer que un elemento flotante se vea igual en todas las resoluciones de pantalla?

Tags: css

Tengo este código

```
{
  width:550px;
  margin-top:3px;
  left:730px;
  padding:31px 78px 12px 51px;
}
```

Necesito que se vea igual ese elemento flotante, que es un cuadrado de texto, que se vea igual en la misma posición, ya sea en resoluciones de 1900 o menores. Como puedo hacer el `css`? a `left` le pongo **%** en lugar de **px**? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar px, puedes usar % o usar el espacio disponible vertical(vh) u horizontal(vw), si nada de eso te convence, puedes crear un media query para manipularlo.

```
@media (max-width: 1900){
    /* Propiedades del elemento a menos de 1900px */
}
```